# The app is rejected because there is already another app with the same identifier in Audience Network

Tags: facebook-audience-network

Help me please. I can't integrate my application in audience network. I have already integrate audience network SDK in my application, And when i see first advertisment in my application, the status in monetization manager is changed to rejected status (The app is rejected because there is already another app with the same identifier in Audience Network). I cant find another application with the same identifier. Already 3 times i deleted all my applications and developer account. But nothings. Tell me please how can I do it.

error_picture:

[image: error_picture]

Comment: Hi, did you fix the issue? If so then would you please share how did you fix?